# Spring Data JPA using Spring Boot application issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am working on Spring Data JPA using Spring Boot. I have done everything required to run the application. I am using H2 as the database. But, nothing is created in the database and also I am not getting any error when accessing application.

Here I am listing all the code what I have written for this application. Could anyone suggest what could be wrong or missing items.

I assume that H2 database would be initialized without any configurations. Do we need any configurations in the application.properties?

```
@Entity
public class Movide implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    String name;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

Then

```
   public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie,Long> {

}
```

Then

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MovieService {

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    public void saveMovie(Movie movie){
        movieRepository.save(movie);    
    }

    public Movie findOne(long id){
        return movieRepository.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

Then

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/movies")
public class MoviessController {
    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/movie/{id}")
    public Movie getMovie(@PathVariable int id){
        Movie movie = movieService.findOne(id);
        System.out.println("Id : "+movie.getId());
        return movie;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/movie/add/{id}")
    public Movie addMovie(@PathVariable int id){
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setId(id);
        movie.setName("Movie 1");
        movieService.saveMovie(movie);
        return movie;
    }
```

Then

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Then

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-boot-web-app-example</finalName>
    </build>
```

When I enabled log, I found the log without values like this:

```
Hibernate: select book0_.id as id1_0_0_, book0_.name as name2_0_0_ from book book0_ where book0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into book (id, name) values (null, ?)
```

But, the values are coming to controller class when i printed the values.

Comment: For starters I suggest extending `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository` and remove your own methods. Next remove `@Transactional` from your controller your service is the transactional boundary. Finally make sure that your `Application` class is in the same package or super package of all your other components (else nothing is going to be detected).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have updated your suggestions. Still not working.

Comment: As mentioned is your `Application` class in a super package or the same package as all other components?

Comment: it is in the super package only. my question is, do we need anything like schema.sql or data.sql to initialize the database. how it would automatically do?

Comment: No. When using the defaults from Spring boot the schema is automatically created... How are you testing this, are you calling the correct URL? What is the startup information when you boot is your controller detect? Do you have an `application.properties` if so please post.

Comment: No. I dont have any application.properties file. I am testing by just accessing the URL in browser. When save method is invoked, no error. I dont know whether data saved. When I access the URL to get stored value it gives null.

Comment: One thing that can help you figure out any issues is logging. For starters I suggest you add `application.properties` and inside it add `spring.jpa.show-sql = true` `logging.level.org.springframework.data=DEBUG`

Comment: You can also bump to version `1.3.M5` to get the auto-configured H2 console. See [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql-h2-console)

Comment: @geoand your idea helped me. I have updated the post with logs. Yes. Some values are null. But, it is coming properly to the controller class

Comment: The null value of the id field is probably due to the `@GeneratedValue` annotation. It's most-likely correct.

Comment: is there any problem with the @GeneratedValue. I am setting that value in the domain class. is that issue?

Comment: @geoand Yes. You are correct. That problem is with GeneratedValue annotation. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is with @GeneratedValue. I have this annotation and also sending the value through bean. So this value become null. What I have done is I have removed this annotations, because I don't want it to be auto generated. Now, its working fine.